# In Word 2007, how do I make a landscape table in a portrait page?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, portrait, landscape

I have a portrait page with headers and footers. I have a table which needs to be in landscape orientation due to space constraints. How do I do that?

**EDIT:**
I actually need the table to be landscape and the header/footer to be portrait.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make a single page have landscape orientation, you must break your document into sections.

Go to where you want to have the page with landscape. Then do the following

- in the ribbon select **Page Layout**
- click on **Breaks** and in **Section Breaks** select **Next Page**
- go to next page, click on **Orientation** and select Landscape - this will make document from this point forward have landscape orientation
- go to the end of this page and repeat above procedure (insert section break, move to next section and select portrait orientation)

[Here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5298745/Changing-Orientation-of-a-single-page-with-Word-2007) is a page explaining it in detail with pictures.

A simpler way to do this is:

1. type some text (it can be as little as a space character),
2. select it,
3. open the “Page Setup” dialog box,
4. go to the “Margins” tab (it should start there by default),
5. click “Landscape” under “Orientation”,
6. choose “Selected text” from the “Apply to” drop-down menu,
7. and click “OK”.

(This creates the section breaks for you.)

---

Regarding the added question information, if I understand correctly you actually want to have portrait oriented header / footer on landscape page.

For example to add page number in portrait orientation you can do following

- create sections with orientation as described above
- go to landscape page where you will position your table
- double click in footer to start editing
- go to footer, in Header and Footer Tools disable "Link to previous"
- click on Page Number button and in Page Margins select position you want
- with the inserted page number selected go to Home tab and select correct justification for text
- move the text box containing page number if it's not in correct position

If you have some more complex information in header and footer you will probably need to play a bit with adding text box in right and left sides of the page, entering the data in the box then changing text direction in Text Box Tools.

Comment: +1 much better than my answer! 8-)

Comment: See my edited question above with more details.

Comment: You mean you want to rotate table by 90 degrees?

Comment: Yes, the table should be 90 degrees.

Comment: Don't know how to rotate whole table, what you can do is rotate text (Table tools -> Layout -> Text direction)  but that won't help much, if it's already an existing table. Another way would be to make it in excel then copy it and do special paste and paste it as image. You can then rotate the image.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to

1. Select and cut your table - on the landscape page
2. Insert (draw) a text box large enough to hold your table
3. Paste the table into the text box.
4. Select the text box and use the rotation handle to rotate the box to portrait
5. Change the page setup to portrait
6. Drag (or set) the text box to the right position on the portrait page.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a single page have a different orientation in Word, the other pages in your document would be portrait but you can alter the page setup for a single page to be landscape instead?

(Or at least this used to be possible, I've just tried to do it in Word 2010 and it doesn't seem to be easily possible)

Answer (score 0):

Use different orientations in the same document:

1. Select the pages or paragraphs whose orientation you want to change.
2. Click Page Layout > Page Setup Dialog Box Launcher.
3. In the Page Setup box, under Orientation, click Portrait or Landscape.
4. Click the Apply to box and click Selected text.

Answer (score 0):

I do realise that I'm replying to a very old question, and that the OP has either solved the problem or given up long ago, but as this is something I've done a lot of I thought I'd post an answer anyhow, in case it helps someone else.

This is what I have done in complex technical reports that flip back and forth between text pages in portrait and tables in landscape.

I'm assuming you've already created your table in landscape and realised that it isn't going to fit.

1. Place the insertion point in the paragraph above the table.
2. Create a new section: **Layout** > **Breaks** > **Next Page**.
3. Place the insertion point in the paragraph after the table.
4. Create a new section: **Layout** > **Breaks** > **Next Page**.

Your table is now in a section of its own, and you can modify page layout -- including the portrait/landscape setting -- without affecting the pages that come before and after.

5. Place the insertion point anywhere in the section containing your table -- but not in the table itself or the next step won't work.
6. In the **Layout** tab, click the button bottom-right to bring up the **Page Setup** dialog.
7. In the **Page Setup** dialog, click **Landscape**, check that **Apply to** is set to ***This section*** and hit **OK**.
8. Check that the section containing your table is now in landscape, with the sections before and after still in portrait. If not, hit undo as many times as necessary and fix the situation -- much easier to fix now than later.
9. Assuming all is ok, go into the footer of the section *after* your landscape section and switch off the ***Same as previous*** option by un-graying the **Link to Previous** entry in the ribbon. Otherwise this section will pick up the footer from the landscape section, and you're about to change it, so you wouldn't want that!
10. Go into the footer of your landscape section and again, switch off ***Same as previous***.
11. Cut and paste everything from the footer into a text box.
12. Format the text box so it has no visible border or shading (assuming that's what you want).
13. Rotate, resize and move it so it's in the correct position (I'm assuming you know how to do that, but don't hesitate to ask).
14. Make any final layout changes within the text box.
15. Exit the footer and check that all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Next solution avoids creating a new sections, which makes it more difficult to change headers, footers, margins, etc. in a consistent manner.

- Insert a Drawing Canvas (Menu, Insert, Illustration, Shapes, New Drawing Canvas at the bottom of the menu).
- Insert a Text Box inside the canvas (Menu, Insert, Illustration, Shapes, Basic Shapes, first element: Text Box).
- Copy the table and the text you want to rotate and paste it inside the textbox, or directly create them inside the Text Box.
- Select and rotate the Text Box.

In the text flow, a Drawing Canvas works like a figure when either is inserted in a paragraph. You can center the paragraph, add space before or after the paragraph, etc.

If the table does not fit the page, you can decrease the font. You can also play with the margins of the cells of the table.

Of course, you could make a table in Excel and copy it in Word as a figure, and rotate it, but the previous solution has a better resolution to file weight ratio.